# after using npm config set script-shell to bash - command not found

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, npm

I'm trying to set the default shell of npm on windows to bash so that it would recognise directories such as ../hello-backend etc...

I'm getting this weird error after setting it with npm config set script-shell `"C:\\Program Files\\git\\bin\\bash.exe"` and whenever I use npm start:

`/usr/bin/bash: C:Users***~1AppDataLocalTempstart-******5629763.sh: command not found`
(asterisk used to blur out potential sensitive info)

Any answers are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out, the reason why is because from npm 8.13 version onwards the script name can't have colon (:) in it e.g. (I've adapted the use of shx as it also wasn't working in the same manner as my issue described above)

```
"scripts": {
    "builduiexercise:try": "shx rm -rf build"
  }
```

it was being used as the grouping-convention before but there's a bug as of version v8.13.0 which prevented it from working
https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5066

this was fixed in a later version of the npm v8.13.2 and it shouldn't cause an issue when you update to the latest version of npm as of this post v8.15.0